# How to customise toolbar title font, I need to give two different fonts to Toolbar title.

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-typeface

Assume my title is "Nearby - Friends" I want to show that as "**Nearby-** 
Friends"

How can I achieve it.

I tired a lot but I can't achieve that.

[image: IMAGE REFERENCE]

HERE is code that I use, I use Typeface

```
TextView text = (TextView) tab.getCustomView();
String subTitle = text.getText().toString().trim();
text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
text.setTypeface(face);
TextView title = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
title.setText("Nearby - ");
title.setTypeface(face);
if (subTitle.equals("NEAR BY")) {
    subTitle = "People";
} else if (subTitle.equals("FRIENDS")) {
    subTitle = "Friends";
} else if (subTitle.equals("FAMILY")) {
    subTitle = "Family";
}
toolbar.setTitle(title.getText().toString() + subTitle);
```

Comment: welcome to SO. please read how to ask with [mcve] before asking

Comment: But I think question relates to Toolbar not directly to TextView. Then how it is duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try This**

> Let say myToolBar is your toolbar layout in xml.

```
Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
```

> Then Add Below code

```
String title = "<b>Near by-</b>Friends"
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml(title));
```

Comment: It looks like it will work, let me try once

Comment: Also try to look @Kishore ans. Using Spannable also you can achieve you have write some extra lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SpannableString to set different font style** for single string sentence in TextView or other text enabled component

```
String strMessage="Nearby- Friends";
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(strMessage);

//"Nearby-" bold font
spannable.setSpan(getTextAppearanceSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, android.R.color.BLACK),Typeface.BOLD), 0, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(spannable);


//"Friends" normal font
spannable.setSpan(getTextAppearanceSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, android.R.color.BLACK),Typeface.NORMAL), 8, strMessage.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(spannable);
```

**TextAppearanceSpan** method to customized text with color

```
/*
 *get customized text with color, style
 */
private TextAppearanceSpan getTextAppearanceSpan(int color, int fontStyle) {
    ColorStateList blueColor1 = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[]{}}, new int[]{color});
    return new TextAppearanceSpan(null, fontStyle, -1, blueColor1, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use two different fonts in `TextView` (e.g. toolbar title)  you should use `Spannable` to apply font to each part of text.

The following solution will apply two custom fonts from your resources.

```
String title = "Nearby- ";
String subtitle = "Friends";
Typeface typefaceBold =  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
Typeface typefaceNormal =  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto.ttf");
SpannableString spannableTitle = new SpannableString(title + subtitle);
spannableTitle.setSpan (new BetterTypefaceSpan(typefaceBold), 0, title.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
spannableTitle.setSpan (new BetterTypefaceSpan(typefaceNormal), title.length(), spannableTitle.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
toolbar.setText(spannableTitle);
```

**BetterTypefaceSpan.java**

```
// Copy of CalligraphyTypefaceSpan
// https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/blob/df1c07f82926831a5c47443bc49f9ff718a4c700/calligraphy/src/main/java/uk/co/chrisjenx/calligraphy/CalligraphyTypefaceSpan.java

import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.MetricAffectingSpan;

public class BetterTypefaceSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {
    private final Typeface typeface;

    public BetterTypefaceSpan(final Typeface typeface) {
        if (typeface == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("typeface is null");
        }

        this.typeface = typeface;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(final TextPaint drawState) {
        apply(drawState);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(final TextPaint paint) {
        apply(paint);
    }

    private void apply(final Paint paint) {
        final Typeface oldTypeface = paint.getTypeface();
        final int oldStyle = oldTypeface != null ? oldTypeface.getStyle() : 0;
        final int fakeStyle = oldStyle & ~typeface.getStyle();

        if ((fakeStyle & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        }

        if ((fakeStyle & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
            paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
        }

        paint.setTypeface(typeface);
    }
}
```